# How do I get a set of coords based on sprite position in pygame?

Tags: pygame

I require a set of 2 coords (X, and Y) based around the corners of the sprite;
instead of one set of coords, in the middle of the sprite

For further context:

Let's say I make a pygame window 10px*10px
if I were to blit in a sprite, that is 10px*10px, at 5,5. How would I get the values of the top left, and bottom right coords?

Comment: You calculate them? Topleft = (5, 5) and bottomright = (5 + 10, 5 + 10) = (15, 15). Remember that when blitting you're passing the coordinates of the topleft corner and **not** the center of the sprite.

Comment: you don't have to calculate top left because with `rect` you can set `rect.width`/`rect.height` and later `rect.center = (5,5)` and it recalculates it and you get correct `rect.topleft`. But you can use `blit(image, rect)` and you don't have to use `rect.topleft`.

Comment: As those who have answered below, the builtin rect class will serve your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The Sprite's `rect` property is ideal for this:

`mysprite.rect.topleft` => (10, 10)

`mysprite.rect.bottomright` => (15, 15)

Pygame `Rect` objects have a whole collection of useful handle attributes you can use.  The full list is in the docs:

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [pygame.Rect](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) to keep object size and position.

If you have image then you can get its size as `rect

```
rect =  image.get_rect()
```

and then you can set its position

```
rect.center = (5, 5)
```

and blit it

```
blit(image, rect)
```

---

`rect` has other usefull properties: `left`, `right` , `top`, `left`, `centerx`, `centerx`, etc.

You can get screen rect

```
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
```

and center element on screen

```
rect.center = screen_rect.center
```

The same way you can center text on button rectangle.

---

`rect` has also methods to check collisions

```
rect.colliderect(other_rect)

rect.collidepoint(mouse_position)
```

---

[pygame.sprite.Sprite](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) uses already `pygame.Rect` to keep size and position as `your_sprite.rect`